# Could someone create tag Rayleigh-distribution?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Apparently I'm far away from the reputation required to do this.

(Or is there a reason not to do this?  Granted one can simply search the site for "Rayleigh," but I assume the tags are there so anyone concentrating on it can subscribe/follow.)

Comment: Tags normally are created to reflect the contents of questions and sometimes of their answers. What threads cause you to recommend creating this tag?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95873/distribution-of-distance-from-center-of-sample-group is mine, although if you search for Rayleigh on CV you'll see the distribution is often referenced in questions.

Comment: Since that's your question, you can create the tag simply by typing it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create your own tags, even on your own questions, until your reputation is >300 (see [privileges: create tags](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)).  Since it is your own question, and seems relevant, I edited your post to create the tag for you.  Be aware that, as noted on the help center page:

> new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period